# Why won't this print?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

```
class anagram_generator:
    words = ""
    letters = []
    def get_words():
        words = raw_input("input the letters\n")
        letters = []
        i = 0

    def sort_words():
        for word in words:
            letters.append(word)
            print letters[i]
            i = i + 1

    get_words()
    sort_words()
```

How come sort_words doesen't print out the words string and the letters array?

Comment: Your use of "for word in words" will go through the single letters in words. Is that what you were intending? I would recommend declaring words to be a list instead of an empty string.

Comment: maybe because get_words() is incomplete, and words = ""?

Comment: @monkut I've edited the code. I thought it would clutter it up.

Comment: words is still empty.  you're using a "local" copy of words, not this instances copy.  To use the instance's copy you have to refer to it with self.words..  but this code shouldn't run anyway, you're sort/get_words() methods are not taking in self.  no real need to make it a class here... remove "class anagram_generator" and dedent.

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you're building a class this way.  Do you realize you're creating attributes on the class itself, not on instances, and will call your functions—which will not work as instance methods—at class definition time?  Are you sure you mean to design your class this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't sure why you put class here because the indent is not true and the way you use "**method**" is not like you want to use class. I have two code. One is using class and other is none.

Firstly, assume that you really want to use class (and I think this best for your problem) :

```
class Generator:
    words = ""  # you should put words and letters here. this will be attribute and both get_words() and sort_words() can see this
    letters = []
    def get_words(self):
        words = raw_input("input the letters\n")
        letters = []
        # i = 0 : no effect. it just local variable with method get_words

    def sort_words(self):
        i = 0  # must be assign value before use
        for word in words:
        letters.append(word)
        print letters[i]
            i = i + 1
```

You should notice, when you use class, each method must have keyword `self`. Here is the test :

```
generator = Generator()
generator.get_words()
generator.sort_words()
```

If this is just **normal function**. your problem doesn't work because some reasons :

1) **words and letters might not be declare as global**. So, when you assign value to those variable in get_words(), sort_words() doesn't see that. If you compile and no error, just some reason , you have assign those value SOMEWHERE in global (type name and assign value somewhere else, not in any function). But in case of that, when you use get_words(), those global still NOT update. So, no "print word" as you see, because "word" you use, doesn't update yet.

2) i variable : must be assign value **before use**.

So, here is the code that I have fixed:

```
def get_words():
    global words
    global letters
    words = raw_input("input the letters\n")
    letters = []
    # global i=0 : you can do that, but SHOULDN'T

def sort_words():
    i = 0 # i must be assign value before use
    for word in words:
        letters.append(word)
        print letters[i]
        i = i + 1
```

and the test will be:

```
get_words()
sort_words()
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variables "words" and "letters" inside your functions as global like so:

```
def sort_words():
global words
global letters
i=0
for word in words:
    letters.append(word)
    print letters[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Variables inside functions can only be accessed in the function, variables from the "outside" are not accessed and in your case stay empty ("" or []), see also [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (search for "global").

Another thing is the i variable which wasn't declared with an initial value, will throw an error as well.